# How to find out the custom dialog box width and height at runtime android

Tags: android, dialog

Hi i am creating one custom dialog box. It's working fine. I am allocated to the width is

```
fill_parent
```

and height is

```
wrap_content
```

How to find out their width and height at runtime.

Comment: Giving height/width to custom dialog box programatically or by xml layout?

Comment: I am giving height/width using xml layout. How to know their height and width using programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

For any view, you can use getHeight() and getWidth() methods to get height and width information.

See [this](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/get-size-width-height-of-view.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine only in the activity. It is not working in the custom dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
AlertDialog.Builder a = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

View v = a.create().getCurrentFocus();
v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

int height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
int width = v.getMeasuredWidth();
```